# put everything from a 2d array into a normal array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2d array called `tiles[x][y]` which goes till 9 so has 100 things inside of it.

How can I get another array and put everything from the 2d array into the normal array?

```
int counter = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++) {
            tiles[y][x] = new loopVak(Color.WHITE, x*tileWidth, y*tileHeight);
            }
        }
```

This is how the 2d array is made, mapwidth and mapheight is 10.

Comment: how are creating a normal array or a single dimension array in the code you have posted could you explain it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert `tiles` to a new 1D Array then you can simply do something like this:

```
int k = 0, newArray[] = new loopVak[100];
for(int i = 0; i < mapWidth; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < mapHeight; j++) {
        newArray[k++] = tiles[i][j];
    }
}
```

If you do not want the 2D array in the first place then you can do something like this:

```
int counter = 0, newArray[] = new loopVak[100];
for(int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++) {
        newArray[counter++] = new loopVak(Color.WHITE, x * tileWidth, y  * tileHeight);
    }
}
```